# Find full path of element in tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I would like to find full path of element in tree. Element can be located in few places.

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWa4Y.png)

My current code:

```
levels = [
    {"L3A": ["L4A"]},
    {"L3B": ["L4B"]},
    {"L3C": ["L4C"]},
    {"L1": ["L2", "L4A"]},
    {"L2": ["L3A", "L3B", "L3C"]}
]

def get_level(name):
    tree = []
    recursive(name, tree)
    return tree

def recursive(name, tree):
    for level in levels:
        for k, v in level.items():
            if name in v:
                tree.append(k)
                recursive(k, tree)

levl = get_level("L4A")
print(levl)
```

**Result**

is:    `['L3A', 'L2', 'L1', 'L1']`

want:  `[['L3A', 'L2', 'L1'], ['L1']]`

**Ultimately want:**

```
L4A in L1 > L2 > L3A

L4A in L1
```

Could you give me some advise how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does `L1` appear twice in your list? Because you have two paths that lead to `L4A`: `L1 -> L2 -> L3A -> L4A` and `L1 -> L4A`, but only one `path` variable to store those paths. Since you use a kind of reverse [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), you have the levels: `L4 -> L3A -> L2 -> L1`, then `L4 -> L1`.

Let's try to elaborate an algorithm. You are dealing with a graph (if you add a root, you get a tree), hence I will use the usual vocbulary: levels are "nodes" and paths between levels are "edges". Here's a good way to proceed:

- given: a node `N`
- find all nodes `P` so that the edge `P-N` exists and store the paths.
- for each `P`, find all nodes `Q` so that the edge `P-Q` exists and store the paths.
- as soon as there is no more `edge` to a node `Q`, ie the current `path` is maximal, return the `path`.

It lacks a bit of precision to be a real algorithm. Let's focus:

```
GIVEN: a node N
let paths_to_explore = [N]
while paths_to_explore is not empty:
    for every path_to_explore:
        try to add a node at the beginning of path_to_explore
        if it fails, yield path_to_explore
```

Before I get to the code, note that you representation of the graph is none of the two usual representations. In your case, you have list of edges, but a dictionary `from_node -> [to_nodes]` is better:

```
edges = {
    "L3A": {"L4A"},
    "L3B": {"L4B"},
    "L3C": {"L4C"},
    "L1": {"L2", "L4A"},
    "L2": {"L3A", "L3B", "L3C"},
}
```

This makes the iteration over edges easier:

```
for from_node, to_nodes in edges.items():
    # do something with nodes
```

Now, the code:

```
def find_reverse_path(name):
    paths = []
    paths_to_explore = [[name]]
    while paths_to_explore:
        path = paths_to_explore.pop() # next!
        to_node = path[0] # the HEAD of the current path
        expanded = False
        for from_node, to_nodes in edges.items():
            if to_node in to_nodes: # there's an edge to the HEAD
                new_path_to_explore = [from_node] + path # new path = from_node + old path
                paths_to_explore.append(new_path_to_explore) # add it to the exploration list
                expanded = True # this path was expanded

        if not expanded: # the path is maximal
            paths.append(path) # use yield if you want to create a generator

    return paths

print(find_reverse_path("L4A"))
```

Output:

```
[['L1', 'L4A'], ['L1', 'L2', 'L3A', 'L4A']]
```

It's an iterative DFS. (It would we harder to know if the path was expanded in a recursive DFS, I think.)

Look at those two lines, they contain the "trick":

```
new_path_to_explore = [from_node] + path # new path = from_node - old path
paths_to_explore.append(new_path_to_explore) # add it to the exploration list
```

Note that `new_path_to_explore` is a **copy** of `path`, that means that we don't just add a node to `paths[-1]` (in place). Why is that? Look at the first steps:

```
1. paths = [[L4A]]
2. paths = [], path = [L4A]
3. append L1-L4A to paths, then append L3A-L4A to paths
4. paths = [[L1, L4A], [L3A, L4A]]
5. paths = [[L1, L4A]], path = [L3A, L4A]
...
```

If we don't make a copy and if we find several edges to the head of the current path, we would have at step 4 `paths = [[L3A, L1, L4]]`. That would be nearly the same issue that you had in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed explanation and solution. I learnd a lot out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the associative map, then apply standard graph search eg. DFS.